# Laravel 6 - Exception Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, serialization

Running into an issue when turning my Mailable into a Queue

When the construct is disabled and the variable is injected directly into the build method, the job loads to the job table without issue, yet the job fails when the worker arrives due to the construct being missing with the following error: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0...

That said, when I enable the construct and remove the variable from the build method, I get an Exception Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed.

Goal is to convert this send() to a queue() so that the db update can be performed ahead of an email being triggered.

**Controller**

```
    public function store(ContactsStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $request->validated();

        $submission = Contact::create(request()->all());
        $request->id = $submission->id;

        $emails = explode(',', config('mail.mailto'));

        $when = now()->addMinutes(1);

        Mail::to($emails)
            ->bcc(['notifications@xxxx.com'])
            ->later($when, new ContactSubmission($request));

        return redirect('/contact/#loc')->with('status', 'success');
    }
```

**Mail Class**

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ContactSubmission extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $topic;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($topic)
    {
        $this->topic = $topic;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.contact-submission')
                    ->subject('XXX - Contact Submission #' . $this->topic->id)
                    ->replyTo($this->topic->email_address);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated here!

Comment: You can't serialize `$request`, because it is a very large object, and is more than you'll need. Pass either `$submission` or `$request->all()`, depending on what you need. You can also build up your own array/object to pass in exactly what you need.

Comment: @aynber I have added $request->all() but the job fails and says: ErrorException: Attempt to read property "id" on array. I am passing the entire submission payload and loading it to the email view, so need to be able to retrieve all the details. Also loading in the returned ID so it can be added to subject and body of the email.

Comment: You'll have to refactor a bunch of code, either by switching everything to an array in the email (harder), or creating an object with `stdClass` and adding in the properties you need, and passing that into your ContactSubmission (easier).

Comment: I just tried your send "$submission" instead of "$request" and the job worked/processed without issue. Thank you for your help with that! @aynber